# using select within select

Tags: c#, linq

Suppose I have the following XML format.

```
<data>
    <appName>Microsoft Word</appName>
    <appId>123</appId>
</data>
```

Where there are multiple data trees within the XML, I have the following code to build a list of data objects.

```
List<DataObj> dataObjList = 
    (
        from dataNode in xmlDoc.Elements("data")
        select new DataObj
        {
            appName = dataNode.Element("appName"),
            appId = dataNode.Element("appId")
        }
    ).ToList();
```

However, I'm running into problems if I add an additional tree under the data tag, like so:

```
<data>
    <appName>Microsoft Word</appName>
    <appId>123</appId>
    <appOptions>
          <Win7Compat>true</Win7Compat>
          <Win7x64Compat>false</Win7x64Compat>
    </appOptions>
</data>
```

And I use the following code:

```
List<DataObj> dataObjList = 
    (
        from dataNode in xmlDoc.Elements("data")
        select new DataObj
        {
            appName = dataNode.Element("appName"),
            appId = dataNode.Element("appId")
            appOptions = 
            (
                from appNode in dataNode.Elements("appOptions")
                select new AppOptionsObj
                {
                    win7Compat = appNode.Element("Win7Compat"),
                    win7x64Compat = appNode.Element("Win7x64Compat")
                }
            ) as AppOptionsObj,
        }
    ).ToList();
```

My appOptions object is always being treated as null. I have a feeling I'm not parsing the  sub tree properly.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `from appNode in dataNode.Element("appOptions")` (single)? Also, what you have posted is not a valid XML. `Win7Compat` and the next sibling not closed.

Comment: I don't believe this is the code you ran -- there are clear syntax error and typos here.  You have to show us the code you are working with if you want help.  The code as posted would just give a bunch of errors.

Comment: Why aren't you simply deserializing this XML to an object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you as casting with `as AppOptionsObj` but your `Select` is actually returning an `IEnumerable<AppOptionsObj>` so the cast results in a `null`. You probably want to use `SingleOrDefault()` to return the single instance instead:

```
List<DataObj> dataObjList = 
    (
        from dataNode in xmlDoc.Elements("data")
        select new DataObj
        {
            appName = dataNode.Element("appName"),
            appId = dataNode.Element("appId")
            appOptions = 
            (
                from appNode in dataNode.Elements("appOptions")
                select new AppOptionsObj
                {
                    win7Compat = appNode.Element("Win7Compat"),
                    win7x64Compat = appNode.Element("Win7x64Compat")
                }
            ).SingleOrDefault(),
        }
    ).ToList();
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks so much.